# Comparing two methods that predict experimental data

Tags: correlation, python, t-test, p-value

I am comparing two methods that predict which residues in two proteins are in contact. I am a bit confused as to how I can compare these methods and draw some conclusion based on some statistic. Currently, I have been using a students t-test on the correlation between the methods and the experimental data. But from that I get that both are significant, i.e. that the p-value is << 0.05. I then conducted another t-test where I compare the means of the two methods, and that one gives me a p-value that confirms the plots that I made.

I have a feeling that I am missing some critical part when I am comparing these methods. In my mind it does not make any sense to compare the means of the methods and the experimental data since that would be like taking the mean of 50% like apples, 20% like bananas and 90% like pears.

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> methodA = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0007, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0075, 0.0034, 0.1645, 0.1611, 0.0464, 0.0514, 0.0273, 0.0049, 0.0264, 0.0112, 0.001, 0.0143, 0.0299, 0.0003, 0.005, 0.0058, 0.0076, 0.1232, 0.0069, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0002, 0.0051, 0.0564, 0.0165, 0.0916, 0.1397, 0.1468, 0.1002, 0.0031, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0008, 0.0, 0.0011, 0.0003, 0.0, 0.0147, 0.0034, 0.0731, 0.0777, 0.1516, 0.1282, 0.0349, 0.0695, 0.0134, 0.0102, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0045, 0.018, 0.022, 0.1027, 0.1663, 0.1726, 0.1473, 0.1402, 0.1605, 0.1603, 0.1322, 0.0976, 0.1379, 0.1289, 0.1477, 0.1413, 0.1634, 0.1672, 0.1453, 0.1487, 0.1584]
>>> methodB = [0.0005, 0.0024, 0.0229, 0.0099, 0.0078, 0.0159, 0.0208, 0.0277, 0.0291, 0.0473, 0.0076, 0.0, 0.0004, 0.0001, 0.0531, 0.1706, 0.1486, 0.1828, 0.1167, 0.0194, 0.1575, 0.0872, 0.0435, 0.0944, 0.1299, 0.0013, 0.0189, 0.0149, 0.0381, 0.0732, 0.0174, 0.0201, 0.0193, 0.0024, 0.0048, 0.0148, 0.0193, 0.0499, 0.0669, 0.072, 0.0582, 0.1345, 0.1353, 0.1321, 0.1846, 0.0071, 0.0204, 0.0, 0.004, 0.0145, 0.0165, 0.0025, 0.0079, 0.0085, 0.0017, 0.0784, 0.0004, 0.0934, 0.0673, 0.1815, 0.218, 0.0264, 0.0455, 0.0481, 0.0201, 0.0382, 0.0094, 0.0092, 0.0138, 0.0076, 0.0211, 0.018, 0.0099, 0.0508, 0.2212, 0.2321, 0.2052, 0.2411, 0.2098, 0.1637, 0.2424, 0.1796, 0.2234, 0.1549, 0.172, 0.2398, 0.1622, 0.14, 0.1928]
>>> ExperimentalData=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3381, 0.1166, 0.3265, 0.0233, 0.0, 0.0117, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0117, 0.0233, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0466, 0.0233, 0.0466, 0.3381, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3148, 0.0117, 0.2215, 0.3381, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0466, 0.0233, 0.0117, 0.3381, 0.2565, 0.2682, 0.3381, 0.07, 0.0466, 0.0233, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.0233]
```

```python
>>> plt.figure(figsize = [12.8, 5])
>>> xs = np.arange(len(methodA))
>>> plt.plot(xs, ExperimentalData, color = 'tab:gray', ls = '--', label = 'Experimental Data')
>>> plt.plot(xs, methodA, color = 'tab:blue', label = 'Method A')
>>> plt.plot(xs, methodB, color = 'tab:green', label = 'Method B')
>>> plt.legend()
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

```python
>>> print(np.corrcoef(methodA, ExperimentalData)[0][1], np.corrcoef(methodB, ExperimentalData)[0][1])
0.46765048698864253 0.6367533471188255
```

```python
>>> print(stats.ttest_ind(methodA, ExperimentalData)[1], stats.ttest_ind(methodB, ExperimentalData)[1])
0.510637136331747 0.021951161091213506
```

From the plot I think it clearly looks as if method A is better than method B, and the t-test supports this but the correlation don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a feeling that I am missing some critical part when I am comparing these methods.

Usually you want to evaluate some overall measure of the *error* or *differences* between observed and model-predicted values. Then the model with the lowest overall error would be the winner.

You should apply your knowledge of the subject matter to choose a measure that works best for your application. Is it the mean-squared error over all residues? The mean absolute error? An error beyond some level (below which you don't care about the error)? The number of residues estimated by the model to be in contact but not actually in contact? The number of observed contacts actually predicted by the method? Only you and your colleagues (guided by the relevant literature) can make that choice.*

Once you choose the appropriate measure of error, you can compare the errors between the two methods *for this particular protein pair*. A statistical test to distinguish the methods *might* be possible, depending on the measure you choose and the distributions of error values. But with only 1 protein pair you can't be sure that the "best" model here would be "best" in any other situation.

---

*The methods don't look that dissimilar overall to my non-expert eye. Method A seems to have fewer false-positive contact predictions where the observed values are 0. Method B seems to capture better the double-peak around residues 15-19 and the late peak near residues 75-80. Which is "better" will depend on your choice of the error measure.